# How to find status of init.d exit scripts which return 0 on failure?

Tags: init-script, init.d, exit, exit-status

It seems that many `init.d` scripts return 0 on failure, in spite of [these recommendations](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html). For example, in `nginx`, running directly:

```
/usr/sbin/nginx -t        # returns 1 (with a bad config)
```

and running via `init.d`:

```
service nginx configtest  # returns 0 (with a bad config)
```

What's the best way of managing the missing status code? It seems there are a few options:

- Parse the output looking for 'fail' whenever you call the command.
- Update the `init.d` scripts to honour the [expected codes described here](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptact.html).
- Update `log_end_msg` in `/lib/lsb/init-functions` so that it does the usual logging and then `exit`s with the exit code it is given initially.